# How I can center the Title in this Titlebar?

Tags: html, css, electron

I need help :)
There is a screenshot of my Electron app. I work on the title bar but I want to center the title, how I can do that, thanks you guys! And as I'm a beginner I don't know if this method to do a Title bar is good, can you say if this is good ?
(And if I can abuse your kindness, how I can do the double button with "valider", it will be useful to me for the future.

**Thank you again very much!**

[What I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HhEN.png)

[Screen of the begin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rtc5.png)

**Html:**

```
<div id="title-bar">
      <button id="close-btn" class="tb-buttons">
        <img src="Images/Close.png" />
      </button>
      <p id="title">CharactersPalette</p>
      <button id="eye-btn" class="tb-buttons">
        <img src="Images/Hide.png" />
      </button>
      <button id="min-btn" class="tb-buttons">
        <img src="Images/Min.png" />
      </button>
    </div>
```

**Css:**

```
/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ TitleBar ~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
}
#title-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
  background-color: #21252b;
}
#title-bar > button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.15s linear;
}
#title-bar > button:hover {
  background-color: #d52015;
}
#title-bar > #title {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f8f4f4;
}
#title-bar > #eye-btn,
#title-bar > #min-btn {
  height: 30px;
  width: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  float: right;
  transition: 0.15s linear;
}
#title-bar > #eye-btn:hover,
#title-bar > #min-btn:hover {
  background-color: #3e4146;
}
#title-bar > button > img {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update you css with below code.

```
#title-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    background-color: #21252b;
    display: flex;            /* Add this */   
    align-items: center;      /* Add this */
}

#title-bar > #title {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f8f4f4;
    margin: 0 auto;           /* Add this */
}
```

Comment: That's save my life :D Thanks you very much! but the title is at the top of title bar it is centered...

Comment: add align-items: center for #title-bar

Comment: i updated my code. please update same in your code, it work 100%

Answer (score 0):

You need add "text align center"

```
#title-bar > #title {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f8f4f4;
  text-align: center;
}
```

complement the answer ...
You can apply text-align:center; to the parent block and apply float: left to the first button.

Comment: Does it support flex?